# Can you use a jQuery handler as .on()'s selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use a jQuery handler `$(...)` as the selector for `.on()`? The code snippet below demonstrates my point: how do I make the circle turn blue if I don't have a plaintext representation of my selector, but *do* have a handler?

```js
// This works.
$(document).on('click', '#wow', function()
{
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
});

// This doesn't work, but I need it to!
var context = $('#wow');
$(document).on('click', context, function()
{
    $(this).css('background-color', '#0000FF');
});
```

```css
#wow
{
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wow"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$('#wow')` exists when you run `var context = $('#wow');` then use that existing object directly

```js
var context = $('#wow');

context.on('click', function()
{
    $(this).css('background-color', '#0000FF');
});
```

```css
#wow
{
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wow"></div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was going to give.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The point of the second parameter of a delegate event handler is a selector to match against the elements the event originates from in the *future*.  Trying to use existing elements as the second parameter does not match the purpose of a delegate event handler.

For more reading: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Otherwise just use a normal event handler.

```
$('#wow').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the element you want is the first in the collection (eg. you selected an id), you can select the first element in the collection and then compare the `event.target` to the element:

```js
const context = $('#wow');
const elm = context.get(0);
$(document).on('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (elm.contains(target)) $(elm).css('background-color', '#0000FF');
});
```

```css
#wow
{
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can give the element a random class and use that:

```
var context = $('#wow');
var cls = 'x' + String(Math.random()).substr(2);
context.addClass(cls);
$(document).on('click', '.' + cls, function() {});
```